# How to use OR condition here

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have a table `records` and another table `categories`

I want to get get all the records in this categories

```
$all_categories = '5,6,7,8';
```

So I am using this code:

```
$query = $this->Records->find('all',[
    'contain' => ['Categories']
]);

if(!empty($search)){
    $query->where(['Records.title LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%']);
}

if(!empty($wilaya)){
    $query->where(['Records.adresse LIKE' => '%'.$wilaya.'%']);
}

if(!empty($cat)){
    $query->where(['Records.category_id =' => $cat]);
} else {
    $categories_array = explode(',',$all_categories);
    foreach($categories_array as $category) {
        $query->where(['Records.category_id =' => $category]);  
    }
}
```

When I use this, I'm getting `AND`-conditions by default.

How can I get `OR`-conditions instead?

Comment: Have you tried `orWhere`?

Comment: Use `IN(<implode array here>)` instead of the `= `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$all_categories = '5,6,7,8';
$array=explode(',',$all_categories);
$query->where(['Records.category_id' => $array], ['Records.category_id' => 'integer[]']);
```

**Note:** Edited answer to add information about the column data type. Won't work without this in CakePHP 3.x.

This equals to:

```
$all_categories = '5,6,7,8';
$array=explode(',',$all_categories);
$query->where(['Records.category_id IN' => $array]);
```

See [Automatically Creating IN Clauses](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#automatically-creating-in-clauses).

Comment: Thanks ,it worked only when i added IN ,it gave me "Cannot convert value to integer " error when i didn't use IN

Answer (score 2):

Use [`IN`](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#automatically-creating-in-clauses):

```
$all_categories = '5,6,7,8';
$categories_array = explode(',',$all_categories);
$query->where(['Records.category_id IN' => $categories_array]);
```

Comment: I believe IN expects `$all_categories` to be an `array`, but a `string` is provided. See [Automatically Creating IN Clauses](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#automatically-creating-in-clauses)